# while starting npm , i encounter this error, can anyone fix this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

[error in react app, while starting npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPgYu.jpg)

I tried deleting node_modules, and install it again did not work. I have attached image regarding error. It's Module not found error, while starting npm. I hope someone could help to fix this error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)